# Need to add highchart colors dynamincally while colors are defeined less

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Kindly refer the below link as sample , consider now I am having one colour which defined in **Highcharts.setOptions({colors: ['#50B432']});** so I am having same data’s to represent the chart which you can refer the link,so I am getting each data colour as single colour, but I need to represent with different colours other than the single colour ,because I am in the situation to define the selected colours into the array and after that data may come more in some scenarios, so on that time I need to resolve this issue by showing individual colour for every data

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/8QufV/][1]
```

Comment: Could you explain what and when should have its color changed? [Series](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) and [points](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) can be updated dynamically.

Comment: your fiddle link  isn't working

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a color array and an object with series as an unique key , refer code below (I have used it to solve similar issue) :

```
var series_color_map = {};

        var graphColor = [ "#808080", "#FF7F50", "#008000", "#6495ED", "#DC143C", "#00FFFF", "#C71385", "#CD5C5C", "#191970", "#708090", "#008B8B",
                           "#CD853F", "#B0C4DE", "#FFC0CB", "#DDA0DD", "#00FF00", "#000000", "#B22222", "#800080", "#FF0000", "#0000FF", "#228B22",
                           "#2F4F4F", "#FFA07A", "#DB7093", "#FAEBD7", "#00CED1", "#20B2AA", "#00FFFF", "#9400D3", "#7FFFD4", "#FF1493", "#778899",
                           "#FF00FF", "#BC8F8F", "#DEB887", "#5F9EA0", "#FFD700", "#BA55D3", "#F4A460", "#7FFF00", "#DAA520", "#2E8B57", "#D2691E",
                           "#00FF7F", "#B8860B", "#F0D58C", "#006400", "#008080", "#D8BFD8", "#8B008B", "#808000", "#556B2F", "#FF8C00", "#EE82EE",
                           "#9932CC", "#8B0000", "#8FBC8F", "#FFFF00", "#FF4500", "#AFEEEE", "#9ACD32"];

        function getGraphColor(serie){
            var color = series_color_map[serie];

            if(null == color){  
                var index = Object.keys(series_color_map).length;
                if(index > graphColor.length)
                    index = 0;

                color = graphColor[index];
                series_color_map[serie] = color;
            }
            return color;
        };
```

and while creating chart , use

```
  var graphColor = getGraphColor(serie);
 chart.addSeries( {
                id : graph_id,
                name : some_name, 
               data : yourData,
               color : graphColor
                } );
```